# Jquery :getting Object Expected Error when using the onchange() for textfield

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a textfield like this

```
<input type = "text" name ="text1" id ="text1" onchange="displayresult()">


function displayresult(){
   alert("testing")
}
```

It is giving object expected error  in IE6.o . when we debug in mozilla it is pointing to function name in this way

```
`function onchange(event) {
     displayresult(); //The cursor is pointed over here 
}`
```

How can i correct this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your description and your example, I think your displayresult() function declaration is below the 'onchange' input text usage.  The solution below uses the document.ready() event, and then uses the ID selector and .change() to register your 'onchange' needs.  you can remove the onchange="displayresult();" in your html if you use my code below

```
<script>
function displayresult(){
   alert("testing");
}
$(document).ready(
    function(event){
     $("#text1").change(function(event){
       displayresult();
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery - you should be able to just use selection via jQuery along with it's [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to help you out, that way you wouldn't need the `displayresult()` in your input declaration. This should help out out:

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#text1').change(function()
    {
        alert("testing");
    });
});
```

So that each time the text is changed in your textbox, you will be alerted.

Comment: You need to make sure - at least mention - that this needs to go in a document ready handler.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I left it out for brevity, but I just added it back in.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to accurately determine why the error is occurring. I would guess that your function is not defined soon enough on the page. Also, you've tagged this question as jQuery related but in your code you are not referencing jQuery at all.

If you want to use jQuery Rionmonster is correct.

If you want to use javascript without jQuery, then you need to provide more information.